# Python typing dict of dicts

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

How do I correctly type hint this python structure:

```py
people={ 
   "john" : {"likes": "apples", "dislikes": "organges"},
   "aisha": {"likes": "kittens", "dislikes": "ravens"}
}
```

EDIT: There can be any keys specified - e.g. "mary","joseph", "carl"...
I understand that the value-dict can be typed as such

```py
class _Preferences(TypedDict):
    likes: str
    dislikes: str
```

But I am not sure how to type the `people` dict itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `TypedDict` for the values and then annotate the `people` dictionary with it:

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class LikesDislikes(TypedDict):
    likes: str
    dislikes: str


people: dict[str, LikesDislikes]

people = {
    "john": {"likes": "apples", "dislikes": "organges"},
    "aisha": {"likes": "kittens", "dislikes": "ravens"},
}
```

Your `people` dictionary doesn't have a fixed structure, but they are strings. You can't do much more about it. If it has fixed structure you could write it as a `TypedDict` too and set `LikesDislikes` as the keys' values. like:

```py
class People(TypedDict):
    john: LikesDislikes
    aisha: LikesDislikes
```

But it doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

```py
people: dict[str, dict[str, str]] = { 
   "john": {"likes": "apples", "dislikes": "oranges"},
   "aisha": {"likes": "kittens", "dislikes": "ravens"}
}
```

This should work on the newer versions of python3